# How do I make a React table sortable by every column?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, rerender, tablesort

I have a table, and I want to make it so that the user can sort it by any column. Here is my code:-

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Table } from "reactstrap";
import { BootstrapTable } from "react-bootstrap-table-next";

function Results(props) {
  var results = props.results;
  console.log(results);
  const [sresults, setSResults] = useState(results);
  const sorter = key =>
    sresults.sort((a, b) => {
      console.log("I am In THE SORTER");
      if (a[key] < b[key]) {
        console.log("RETURNING -1");
        return -1;
      }
      if (a[key] > b[key]) {
        console.log("RETURNING 1");
        return 1;
      }
      console.log("RETURNING 0");
      return 0;
    });
  if (!props.results) return "no data";
  if (!Array.isArray(props.results)) return "results are not array";
  function rows() {
    let result = sresults.map((result, index) => {
      return (
        <tr key={result.Book_Name}>
          <th scope="row">{index}</th>
          <td>{result.Book_Name}</td>
          <td>{result.Author}</td>
          <td>{result.S_no}</td>
          <td>{result.Series_Name}</td>
          <td>{result.Fiction_Non_fiction_Companion_Prequel}</td>
          <td>{result.Genre}</td>
          <td>{result.Kindle_Real}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
    return result;
  }
  function ssorter(key) {
    setSResults(sorter(key));
    console.log(sresults);
  }
  return (
    <Table hover bordered responsive>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>{"S.no of the Books Found"}</th>
          <th>{"Book Name"}</th>
          <th>{"Author"}</th>
          <th>
            {"S.no"}
            <button onClick={() => ssorter("S_no")} />
          </th>
          <th>{"Series Name"}</th>
          <th>{"Fiction/Non fiction/Companion/Prequel"}</th>
          <th>{"Genre"}</th>
          <th>{"Kindle or Real"}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{rows()}</tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}

export default Results;
```

I tried **react-bootstrap-table-next**, but I get a fatal error, saying that it expects a string. The tutorial I followed for react-bootstrap-table-next is [here](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Sort%20Table&selectedStory=Enable%20Sort&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel).

Thanks in advance, and please let know if you need any more details.

Edit:The state changes. I have confirmed this. But, the page doesn't rerender.

Answer (score 0):

attach to each TH a `onClick` function. Make use of `useState`. Put your `results` into this state. Then on onClick trigger sort basing on table column. i.e.

```
const sorter = key => results.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a[key] < b[key]) { return -1; }
  if(a[key] > b[key]) { return 1; }
  return 0;
})
```

with `onClick={() => setResults(sorter('Book_Name'))}` it's just some crude code, it could be improved but should give you idea. Now of course you need to display this somehow on table row headers (i.e. arrows) and implement sort direction (ASC, DESC).

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not working. I have edited the code in my question to after I added State. Could you see what's wrong?

Comment: Your sorter sorts but doesn't do anything with sorted data. Take a closer look at my pseudocode -> `setResults(sorter('Book_Name')` also you've made spelling and made `ssorter`

Comment: Ssorter is another function. Your pseudocode is inside the ssorter function.

Comment: The state changes. I have confirmed this. But, the page doesn't rerender.